# Signs for the enter key, page up and page down

Tags: bash

anyone advise how to add characters to press enter, page up and page down

```
UP_ARROW=$'\x1b[A'
DOWN_ARROW=$'\x1b[B'
LEFT_ARROW=$'\x1b[D'
RIGH_TARROW=$'\x1b[C'

ENTER=???
PAGE_UP=???
PAGE_DOWN=???
```

Thank You Very Much

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand at all what you wrote :-(

Comment: that blue thingy there is a link. click on it.

Comment: Blue thingy? And where? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then the character that you're interested in. You'll get a representation of it in response.

Note that many of these keystrokes are dependent on which terminal you're using.

Also, see `man 5 terminfo`. You can get values for the page up key, for example, by doing

```
tput kpp | hexdump -C
```

`kpp` is "previous-page key"